# Perform Bitwise XOR on 2 strings in ruby

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation, xor

I am trying to perform a Bitwise XOR on two key strings in ruby:

key1: 0123456789abcdeffedcba9876543210

key2: 00000000000000000000000000000000

Could someone please tell me how to do this, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

[Unpack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-unpack) into bytes, zip together, map xor, re-[pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack).

```
s1='0123456789abcdeffedcba9876543210'
s2='00000000000000000000000000000000'
xored = s1.unpack('C*').zip(s2.unpack('C*')).map{ |a,b| a ^ b }.pack('C*')
# => "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\a\b\tQRSTUVVUTSRQ\t\b\a\x06\x05\x04\x03\x02\x01\x00"
```

Comment: Thanks! I am expecting the result to be: “0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA9876543210”. Do you know how to get this from the two input string s1 and s2. Thanks

Comment: That isn't a bitwise xor of the characters that you want. It's not entirely clear what you want . . . to get your desired string you could just do `s1.upcase`, but of course that doesn't involve `s2` at all. Could you perhaps alter the question to have a non-trivial `s2` so it is clearer what function you are searching for.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone please tell me how to do this?

The XOR operator in Ruby is `^`. It can be used as both bitwise and boolean, depending on its argument (remember that `^` is an operator *and* a method `.^(x)`). In the default class `String` is doesn't exists but you can easily implement it yourself:

```
class String

    # converts to array of chars
    def to_a
        ret = []
        self.each_char do |c|
            ret.push c
        end
        return ret
    end

    # given two numeric strings,
    # returns the bitwise xor string
    def ^(s)
        aa = self.to_a
        ab = s.to_a
        lc = (aa.count < ab.count) ? aa.count : ab.count
        ret = ""
        lc.times do |i|
            x = aa[i].to_i ^ ab[i].to_i
            ret = ret + x.to_s
        end
        return ret
    end

end
```

This is just an example and it hasn't been tested.

---

> If I was going to convert each byte to binary before performing bit-wise exclusive-or. How would I do that?

Well, you want to take a look at [String#bytes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-bytes) or [String#each_byte](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-each_byte) and implement the code above with those methods instead.

Comment: If I was going to convert each byte to binary before performing bit-wise exclusive-or. How would I do that?

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to do this with String#bytes or String#each_byte. Sorry I am new at this! Much appreciate it